# My cron job is not sending an email with any output, I see only a blank email

Tags: cron, email

Can someone please help me here. My cron job is not sending an email with output. While I run the shell script manually it generates an email with output.

Here is the script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

MAILLIST=<email>
LogDirectory='/app/oracle/admin/monitor/'

DBUSER='rman'
DBUSERPASSWORD='rman01'
DB='pdcatdb'
SUBJECT="RMAN Backup Status Report"
ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2_64

${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -s <<EOF  > ${LogDirectory}/query.log
${DBUSER}/${DBUSERPASSWORD}@${DB}
set pagesize 20000
set linesize 2000
set wrap off
set trimspool on
set feedback off
set echo off
set termout off
set heading off
set underline off
set colsep ','
SELECT RTRIM(A.DB_NAME)||'---->'||
       LTRIM(A.STATUS) "BACKUP_STATUS"
  FROM rman.RC_RMAN_STATUS A,
       (  SELECT DB_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, MAX (END_TIME) END_TIME
            FROM rman.RC_RMAN_STATUS
           --WHERE     OBJECT_TYPE IN ('DB FULL', 'DB INCR')
           WHERE     OBJECT_TYPE IN ('DB INCR')
                 AND STATUS IN ('COMPLETED', 'COMPLETED WITH ERRORS', 'FAILED')
                 AND OPERATION IN ('BACKUP', 'BACKUP COPYROLLFORWARD')
        GROUP BY DB_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE) B
 WHERE     A.OBJECT_TYPE IN ('DB FULL', 'DB INCR', 'ARCHIVELOG')
       AND STATUS IN ('COMPLETED', 'COMPLETED WITH ERRORS', 'FAILED')
       AND OPERATION IN ('BACKUP', 'BACKUP COPYROLLFORWARD')
       AND A.DB_NAME = B.DB_NAME
       AND A.END_TIME = B.END_TIME
       AND A.OBJECT_TYPE = B.OBJECT_TYPE
       AND A.end_time > sysdate-7
       order by 1
       /
EOF
mailx -s "Rman Backup Report" <email> < /app/oracle/admin/monitor/query.log
```

Comment: Your `mailx` command at the bottom of the script appears to reference explicit emails. Is this different from the unused MAILLIST variable at the top of the script? (You also define `$SUBJECT` and `$LogDirectory` but neither is used in the `mailx` command you've shown.)

Comment: @roaima, I commented all the variables that I've not used and tried, no luck. I also commented all the variables and ran the script by specifying full path, still no luck.

Comment: Please can you show the `crontab` entry for this command. What errors do you get, if any, as the `cron` output (not your `mailx` output as you've already said that's empty).

Comment: If you run your script manually like this : `env -i HOME="$HOME" /path/to/script`, do you get any errors? That kind of simulates the way cron will run it.

Comment: You could also tack on 2>&1 to your sqlplus incantation, and capture any output that goes to stderr to your logfile, which hopefully would net you the reason for why it generated no output on stdout. cron has potentially also sent an email with any output from the shell-script in general.

Comment: Thank you all, my sctipt is working now after adding   source /home/user/.bash_profile, Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Ravikanth: If [steve's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216022/80216) solved your problem, you should "accept" it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Those environment variables such as `${ORACLE_HOME}` are perhaps in your bash profile.  This does not get read via cron automatically.

Insert the line below after the #!/bin/bash.

```
source /home/user/.bash_profile
```

Comment: `$ORACLE_HOME` is defined near the top of the script

Comment: Thank you for responding, when I added the line, it is throwing below error ./rman_backup_report.sh: line 2: /home/user/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
infact, If you look at my script I've defined these in my script as a variables       DBUSER='rman'
DBUSERPASSWORD='rman01'
DB='pdcatdb'
SUBJECT="RMAN Backup Status Report"
ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2_64

Comment: @steve, Thank you so much , I added the bash_profile to my script and it works like charm! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I have to resurrect this because I was googling this
the simple solution is (at least in my case) to use shebang

```
#!/bin/csh
```

because orasid uses this shell as standard shell

Comment: There is some assumption about where the Oracle environment is being set up that you do not mention. In your case, it may be in the `csh` shell's initialization file. However, for the user in the question [it seems to be](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216020/my-cron-job-is-not-sending-an-email-with-any-output-i-see-only-a-blank-email#comment366886_216022) in their `.bash_profile` file.